# excel-vba: Turn text from cells with particular format into an object suitable for outlook e-mail body, while maintaining the same format properties

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is the following:

I want to define a range, including cells in my spreadsheet that contain formatted text (bold font), and turn it into any object that I can later use as the body for an outlook e-mail.

One of the ways I have tried so far is via the RangetoHTML function by Ron de Bruin  (http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm). However, the function brings the text cells into another excel workbook which finally yields a table in the outlook e-mail. I want to keep the very same format that I start with in my excel cells. That is, it must be lines of ordinary text and not a table-like body in the mail.

That's my current code:

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Sheets("Preparation").Range("A90:A131")
With Selection
.Value = rng.Text
.Font.Bold = rng.Font.Bold
.Font.Color = rng.Font.Color
End With

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Display   
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: *I want to keep the very same format that I start with in my excel cells* - What exact format is changing? Can you show a picture of what happens versus what you want? I have found `RangetoHTML` to be pretty solid in keeping desired formatting when pasting to email.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot send a photo because it would disclose non-public information. The problem with RangetoHTML though is that it crops the text from my excel cells and brings them again into a temporary excel workbook. Finally, what I'll have as a HTMLBody of my e-mail is again something in table format which is just not the same as a plain text with the same breaks and same bold fonts as in the original text.

Comment: Basically, the text you will find in the e-mail is a word table and I don't want that

Comment: If you can blot out sensitive information, or create mock-up, you can send the picture. Or you can adjust the Excel range to suit your needs. I have never seen `RangetoHTML` not suit my needs even if I needed to be a bit creative. Without a photo, hard to help more.

Comment: I just tried but I cannot upload a picture due to compliance reasons.

However, I do not really see why we do not find accordance when we´re both acquainted with RangetoHTML :D If you create text in excel by filling cells, what the function does is copying it into a new temporary workbook and transforming this into HTML format. What you can *clearly* see in the outlook mail (i.e. the ouput of the whole thing) - at least for 2013 version - is that the text body has a table format. Like you set up a table in a word doc. How to get that into a e.g. rich text?

Comment: (Moreover, one cannot post pictures without 10 of those stupid reputation points)

Comment: And no I don´t mean rich text instead of HTML I mean that I have a normal text like in a rich text which maintains my formatting like bold font lines and the breaks, just NOT a table of text

Comment: I just added .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText beneath which does indeed remove the table format into the format I want but then the bold font gets lost...

Comment: I appreciate your frustration. However, there isn't much more I can do without seeing the details of the issue. In this case, seems the devil is in the details. Another option you have is to build the body of the mail yourself using `HTML` syntax and `.HTMLBody`.

Comment: Is there a way to send pictures to you users so that you could use it?

Comment: Please merge your questions.  If your first question was unclear, rephrase it.  Do not ask another question.  It is likely that one or both of your questions will be closed as unclear.  I think I have the answer you seek but I will not post it until I know which question will be kept.

Comment: My understanding of your question is as follows.  I have a column in a worksheet which I wish to output as the Html body of an email.  Cells can be bold or not-bold and left or right aligned. I wish this formatting to be carried across to the Html.  If a cell is empty, I need a blank line in the Html.  I have tried Ron de Bruin’s RangeToHtml but the output is unsatisfactory because …. .  Is there an alternative approach that will meet my requirement?

Comment: If you have more types of formatting, add them to my list.  In the image you post. The rows have a grey background and are separated by wide, white border. Is this really the appearance you seek?

Comment: I have just looked at the name of your image. I assume this image was created using Ron de Bruin's routine which explains why it is unsatisfactory.

Comment: Hello Tony. Is it more clear now? I just want to get rid of this table thing. I just want to have the very same output as in the picture but not as a table, just ordinary lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

Ron de Bruin’s RangeToHtml shows how to use Excel’s PublishObjects to convert a worksheet range to Html that can be used as the body of an email.  I am sure this has helped thousands of developers.

The difficulty that RdeB overcomes is that PublishObjects is designed to create and maintain webpages.  His routine outputs to a file and then reads that file because that is the only way to get the Html string required for the email body.

The difficulty that RdeB cannot overcome is that PublishObjects create poor quality, proprietary CSS.  By “poor quality”, I mean that there is a lot of unnecessary CSS and that row heights and column widths are defined in points to give sizes suitable for a PC.  By “proprietary”, I mean it uses styles such as `mso-ignore:padding` and `mso-number-format:General` that only Microsoft browsers are guaranteed to understand.  It appears the major browsers are able to cope but many people have found that some newer browsers cannot cope and display rubbish.

To demonstrate this and to test my code, I created a worksheet based on your image.  Rows 16 to 18 are right-aligned because I have specified this.  Rows 20 to 22 are right aligned because this is the Excel default for numeric, date and time values.  Its appearance is:

[image: Image of original worksheet]

You can use your real data.

Copy this code to your workbook:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test1()

  Dim PathCrnt As String
  Dim PathFileCrnt As String
  Dim RngStr As String
  Dim WshtName As String

  PathCrnt = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"       ' ## Output to the same folder as workbook holding the macro
  PathFileCrnt = PathCrnt & "Test1.html"   ' ## Change if you do not like my filename
  WshtName = "Sheet1"                      ' ## Change to your worksheet
  RngStr = "A1:A28"                        ' ## Change to your range

  With ThisWorkbook
    With .PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
                             Filename:=PathFileCrnt, _
                             Sheet:=WshtName, _
                             Source:=RngStr, _
                             HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
                        .Publish (True)
    End With
  End With

End Sub
```

You will need to change some of the statements near the top marked with ##

Run this macro to output your range to the file.

On my laptop, Microsoft Edge, Microsoft Internet Explorer and Google Chrome all display the file and all look the same although IE and Chrome are slow to display.  The column is down the centre of the window:

[image: Output created by PublishObjects]

There are none of the background grey cells and wide, white border you showed. However, I have not tried to display it within Outlook.

Now look at the file with your favourite text editor.  Notice how much CSS is repeated.  Notice how many style start “mso-” indicating they are Microsoft extensions.  Notice the heights and widths measured in “pt” (points).  Some Html display engines can cope but some cannot.

I suspect that PublishObjects has not been maintained.  It was available with Excel 2003 and perhaps earlier.  Some of the old Microsoft CSS extensions now have standard CSS equivalents but PublishObjects has not been updated to use them.

I have my own RangeToHtml written entirely in VBA.  It will handle all formatting except borders.  My code is far too big to post on Stack Overflow so I have extracted the bits you need.  You apparently need bold or not bold and left or right alignment.  I do not know if you specify right alignment or if you have numeric fields which right align by default so I handle both.

My function ColToHtml(range) returns a complete Html file for the first column of a range.  My code does not create a temporary workbook or a temporary file.  It produces clean, crisp Html and Css.  It produces a table because you cannot have right-alignment outside a table.  However, with no borders, it is not obvious the output is a table.  The only difference in appearance is that the table is left aligned.  If you prefer a centred table, it would be an easy change.

This was my test routine:

```
Sub Test2()

  Dim Rng As Range

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(28, 1))
  End With

  Debug.Print ColumnToHtml(Rng)

End Sub
```

It outputs the Html string to the Immediate Window.  I then copied it to a file.  I could have used VBA to write to a file but this was easier.  When I opened the file with Microsoft Edge, it looked the same.  Have a look at this second file with your favourite text editor.  Notice how much smaller it is.  The PublishObjects version is 6,901 bytes while this second version is 1,681 bytes.  Notice how only standard Css is used and that the minimum of Css is used.  This allows the display engine to make its own decisions about how to display the file based on the type of output device.

My last test was:

```
Sub Test3()

  ' This will need a reference to Microsoft Outlook nn.0 Outlook library
  ' where nn is the number of the Outlook version you are using.

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim MailItemNew As Outlook.MailItem

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(28, 1))
  End With

  With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
  End With

  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  Set MailItemNew = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  With MailItemNew
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = ColumnToHtml(Rng)
    .Display
  End With

  With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With

  Set MailItemNew = Nothing
  Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

This outputs the range to Outlook.  I have used your code as a template but have referenced the Outlook library so I can use Outlook objects and constants.  I had to reduce the font size to get it all on the screen at one time giving:

[image: Appearance within Outlook]

Again this has the same appearance except that the first letter of each line has been capitalized.  I do not know how to stop the Outlook email editor doing this.

Incidentally, I selected the entire email and got the same appearance as in the image you posted.

The code for ColumnToHtml is below.  Note that CellToHtml is the routine that actually creates the Html for a cell.  It only handles bold and right alignment but it should be obvious that it would be easy to add other cell-level formats.

```
Function ColumnToHtml(ByRef RngCol As Range) As String

  ' Returns the first or only column of rng as a borderless table
  ' so it appears as a formatted list of rows.

  Dim RngCell As Range
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim Table As String

  ' Build an Html table of the cells within the first column of RngCol
  ' ==================================================================

  Table = Space(4) & "<table border=""0"">" & vbLf
  For RowCrnt = RngCol.Row To RngCol.Row + RngCol.Rows.Count - 1
    Set RngCell = RngCol.Worksheet.Cells(RowCrnt, RngCol.Column)
    Table = Table & Space(6) & "<tr>" & CellToHtml(RngCell) & "</tr>" & vbLf
  Next
  Table = Table & Space(4) & "</table>"

  ' Build an Html file envelope around the table
  ' ============================================

  ColumnToHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN""" & _
                       """http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd"">" & vbLf & _
                "<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" xml:lang=""en"" lang=""en"">" & vbLf & _
                "  <head></head>" & vbLf & _
                "    <meta http-equiv=""Content-Type""content=""text/html; charset=utf-8""/>" & vbLf & _
                "    <style>" & vbLf & _
                "      td.bold {font-weight:bold;}" & vbLf & _
                "      td.hAlign-right {text-align:right;}" & vbLf & _
                "    </style>" & vbLf & _
                "  </head>" & vbLf & _
                "  <body>" & vbLf & Table & vbLf & _
                "  </body>" & vbLf & _
                "</html>"

End Function
Function CellToHtml(ByRef RngCell As Range) As String

  ' Convert a single cell to Html.
  ' This code handles: value, bold or not-bold (default) and left )default) or
  ' right-alignment.

  ' Note RngCell.Value is the value perhaps "1234" or "42999".
  '  and RngCell.Text is the display text perhaps "1,234" or "21-Sep-17".
  ' This is particularly important with dates and time where the
  ' value is unlikely to be what is displayed.
  ' Dates are held as days since 1-Jan-1900 and times are held as
  ' seconds-since-midnight / seconds-in-a-day. It is the NumberFormat that
  ' determine what you see.

  Dim BoldCell As Boolean
  Dim RAlignedCell As Boolean
  Dim Style As String
  Dim StyleNeeded As Boolean

  CellToHtml = "<td"

  ' Add interior formatting here if required

  If RngCell.Value = "" Then
    ' Ignore font and alignment formatting of empty cell.
  Else
    ' Test for formats
    BoldCell = False
    RAlignedCell = False
    Style = ""
    StyleNeeded = False

    If RngCell.Font.Bold Then
      BoldCell = True
      StyleNeeded = True
    End If

    If RngCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight Or _
       (RngCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral And _
        (IsNumeric(RngCell.Value) Or IsDate(RngCell.Value))) Then
      RAlignedCell = True
      StyleNeeded = True
    End If

    If StyleNeeded Then
      CellToHtml = CellToHtml & " class="""
      If BoldCell Then
        If Style <> "" Then
          Style = Style & " "
        End If
        Style = Style & "bold"
      End If

      If RAlignedCell Then
        If Style <> "" Then
          Style = Style & " "
        End If
        Style = Style & "hAlign-right"
      End If

      CellToHtml = CellToHtml & Style & """"

    End If
  End If

  CellToHtml = CellToHtml & ">"  ' Terminate "<td"
  If RngCell.Value = "" Then
    ' Blank rows are displayed narrow.  Use Non-blank space so display at homral width
    CellToHtml = CellToHtml & "&nbsp;"
  Else
    CellToHtml = CellToHtml & RngCell.Text
  End If
  CellToHtml = CellToHtml & "</td>"

End Function
```

One last comment.  You have not selected anything so I do not see the purpose of this code:

```
With Selection
  .Value = rng.Text
  .Font.Bold = rng.Font.Bold
  .Font.Color = rng.Font.Color
End With
```

Comment: Hey Tony. Ok now I understand what you mean! I'm sorry I didn't know that it was a problem to put in different questions related to the same idea. Indeed I wanted to check all my different approaches so far.

Comment: Anyway, yes this function would definitely solve all my problems. I would just need to know moreover how to make it an object that can be used for .HTMLBody = but I guess that's trivial for experienced users.

Comment: P.S. I deleted all questions without answers from other users. Hope that's ok because I get warned to not delete posts with such answers. Maybe you know another way

Comment: (1) I will construct a proper answer and post it later today. (2) I do not understand " ... how to make it an object that can be used for .HTMLBody = ... ". HTMLBody is a MailItem property of type string.  So `.HTMLBody = "<html>...</html>"`. Why do you think you need an object? (3) We can worry about the other questions with answers later.

Comment: Hey Tony
1) How do I now attach the HTML document of SubTest1() to a .HTMLBody command in a macro?
2) As for me, the ColumnToHTML still yields a table in outlook :( you mentioned you didn't check how it was for you right?

Comment: @PascalStefanBuehrig. I had not checked output to Outlook at the time I wrote, tested and documented Test1 and Test2.  I should have removed that remark later.  Look at Test3 which outputs to Outlook.  The image under the Test3 code shows what the range looks like in Outlook.

Comment: @PascalStefanBuehrig  Yes, ColToHtml creates a table.  I do not know of anyway of right aligning text in Html or Css except within a table.  However, since the table does not have visible borders, it does not look like a table.  I mentioned that if I selected the table I could get the appearance you showed in your image. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @PascalStefanBuehrig  Let me rephrase the previous comment. You can left, centre or right align text in Html but, as far as I know, only for headers, paragraphs and other block level elements. I think it would be at least very difficult and perhaps impossible to get the appearance you seek without tables.

Comment: I understand. Thanks anyway for your great help.

Comment: @PascalStefanBuehrig.  I do not understand.  Have you got what you wanted or have you given up?  Both PublishObjects and my code give the output I think you want on my PC. My code gives the output I think you want on any device. What am I missing?

Comment: Hey Tony. I implemented you code but still get a table-based output in the e-mail :( I found another solution though. I just wrote the hardcoded parts of the excel text in the HTML body and defined variant parts as strings to be included in the HTML body

Comment: @PascalStefanBuehrig.  How do you right align text without a table?  Why the objection to a table with invisible borders?